# Reestruturar tabela dividindo as colunas em linhas

Tags: mysql

Tenho uma tabela na seguinte estrutura:

```
| campo1 | campo2 | campo3 | campo4 |
| --------------------------------- |
| valor1 | valor2 | valor3 | valor4 |
| valor5 |  NULL  |  NULL  | valor8 |
```

Entre outras colunas não relevantes

Estou reestruturando o banco, e preciso transformar em uma estrutura assim:

```
| campo  |
| ------ |
| valor1 |
| valor2 |
| valor3 |
| valor4 |
| valorN |
```

É possível fazer isso apenas com SQL? Como?

São exatos 4 colunas que preciso transformar em 4 linhas ou menos (alguns campos são nulos). A chave primária não está sendo referenciada em nenhum outro lugar, não sendo importe (já exclui o campo e irei inserir novamente quando a tabela estiver reestruturada)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso seria uma operação chamada UNPIVOT. 
Para fazer isso no MySQL, use o [UNION ALL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/union.html), assim:

```
select campo1 from mytable where campo1 is not null
union ALL
select campo2 from mytable where campo2 is not null
union ALL
select campo3 from mytable where campo3 is not null
union ALL
select campo4 from mytable where campo4 is not null
```

Veja funcionando no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ced17e/2).

Para inserir esses dados, **considerando valores duplicados**, em outra tabela, faça assim:

```
Insert into `NovaTabela` (campo) Select campo from (

select campo1 as campo from mytable where campo1 is not null
union all
select campo2  as campo from mytable where campo2 is not null
union all
select campo3  as campo from mytable where campo3 is not null
union all
select campo4  as campo from mytable where campo4 is not null) T;
```

Veja funcionando no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7600f/2). Você pode ver que o número de resgitros original é 100 e que após o insert ficaram 396. A diferença são os nulos que foram retirados

## Nota

Uma consulta com UNION vai eliminar valores duplicados.
Se você fizer

```
select 'A' as campo
union
select 'A'  as campo
union
select 'B'  as campo
union
select 'C'  as campo
```

Voce vai obter somente três registros A,B e C

Para remover este comportamento use o UNION ALL
    select 'A' as campo
    union all
    select 'A'  as campo
    union all
    select 'B'  as campo
    union all
    select 'C'  as campo

Desta forma voce obtem os 4 registros: A, A, B, C; como pode ser visto neste [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/53783)

Comment: O problema é que preciso mudar a estrutura da tabela, não apenas trazer os dados de uma forma diferente

Comment: Adicionei um exemplo de inserção em outra tabela.

Comment: Não sabia que era possível inserir um "array" pelo SQL, achava que precisava colocar vários `VALUE( ... )`, valeu pela ajuda

Comment: Valeu, vou pegar algumas linhas dos resultados e comparar pra ver se está tudo certo